# Can't use devise IntegrationHelpers on Rail's minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, minitest

I am using '[devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.6'.

My [controller test](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-tests) work, but I can't get the [integration test](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#integration-tests) to run

test_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/rails/capybara"
require "mocha/mini_test"
require "minitest/reporters"
require 'shoulda/context'
Minitest::Reporters.use! Minitest::Reporters::SpecReporter.new # spec-like progress

include Devise::TestHelpers

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.

  include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  fixtures :all
end
```

fixture:

```
default_user:
  name: "User"
  email: "example@example.org"
  encrypted_password:   "exampleexample"
```

example test file:

```
class PostsTests < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers 

  test 'authenticated users can see posts' do
    sign_in users(:default_user)
  end
end
```

Error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Devise::Test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to be working with an old version. I just updated  to 4.1.1

```
gem 'devise', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.1'
```